# navigationBar color and title

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I had a lot of .xib files and I try to recreate them programmatically.

The only problem is, is that I can't customize my navigationbar any more.

De versions function is called by another view with multiple bar button items, so the code is generic to other functions to.

```
- (void)versions
{
    VersionsViewController *verController = [[VersionsViewController alloc] initWithDocument:document];
    [verController setDelegate:self];

    [self loadPopupView:verController];

    [verController release];
}

- (void)loadPopupView:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (popOverController != nil && [popOverController isPopoverVisible]) 
    {
        [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

    if(![popOverController isPopoverVisible] || ![popOverController.contentViewController isKindOfClass:[viewController class]])
    {
        popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
        popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);

        UIBarButtonItem *buttonLocation;

        if([viewController isKindOfClass:[CommentaryViewController class]])
            buttonLocation = commentaryButton;
        else if([viewController isKindOfClass:[PropertiesViewController class]])
            buttonLocation = propertiesButton;
        else
            buttonLocation = versionsButton;

        [popOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:buttonLocation permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

VersionsViewController.m

```
- (id)initWithDocument:(Document *)doc
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        self.document = doc;
        self.title = @"other title"; //does not work either

        //I just tried everything I could think of :P
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        self.navigationItem.titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Can someone see what I did wrong?

EDIT:

NSLOG from self.title and self.navigationController.title are both 'null'

When I create a navigationController add the view and add the navigationController to the popup i get 2 bars and then I can set the title of the navigationController but still not the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just curious: if you have working nib files, why are your recreating them programmatically?

In `initWithDocument:`, you haven't assigned a `nvaigationController` yet. You'll need to build one of those by hand, and install `VersionViewController` in it (`navigationController` will be set after you've done that). Having all of this work automatically is one of the reasons we use nib files.

**EDIT** Anytime "nothing happens" check that the object you're messaging is not `nil`. I'm certain `navigationController` is still `nil` when you get to it. You should also `NSLog` the objects you care about and look at their addresses. You probably are accidentally creating multiple views or multiple navigation controllers. This is very common to do when you try to build this stuff by hand. Nibs are the correct solution in most cases.

Comment: The reason for creating them programmatically is performance. .xib files are just big XML files and I just need a navigationbar and a table view, nothing complex. The weird thing is, is that I see the bar with a title witch is never set. When I create a navigationController add the view and add the navigationController to the popup i get 2 bars and then I can set the title of the navigationController but still not the color.

Comment: You will not improve performance by getting rid of nib files. Nib files are compiled. XIB files are the XML source for them. There is a small disk-access cost which is there to improve memory usage. If it's a problem, you can preload the nib by accessing the view controller's `view` property. Thawing a nib is generally cheaper than generating the objects, since all the values are freeze-dried. but the difference in either case is tiny and not a place for performance optimizations.

Comment: Very thanks for the good and clear explanation. I think I just recreate the nib file if the performance isn't that better without them. This is taking to much time anyway. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)versions
{
    VersionsViewController *verController = [[VersionsViewController alloc] initWithDocument:document];
    [verController setDelegate:self];
    UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:verController];
    [self loadPopupView:navC];
    [verController release];
    [navC release];
}
```